# JSF classpath resolution

Tags: jsf, classpath, java-ee-8

I started to work on a legacy jsf code which contains duplicated class and jsf names in different packages and different wars, of course. One for the operators, the other for the customers.
I would like to know that it's working by accident or the classpath resolution guarantees that the jsf file will find the proper backing bean. Both beans are named beans.

The structure of the project looks like this:

- com.company.operator (war module)

  - com.company.operator.Back (class name)
  - operator-module/src/main/webapp/operator/frontend1.xhtml (first jsf which references ${back.someFunction})
- com.company.customer (war module)

  - com.company.customer.Back (class name)
  - customer-module/src/main/webapp/customer/frontend2.xhtml (2nd jsf referencing ${back}
- com.company.ear (ear module)

The whole application is packaged into the same ear.
Is it possible that the reference ${back} in frontend2.xhtml is resolved to com.company.operator.Back, the class in the other module?

IntelliJ founds the proper references.

Answer (score 1):

Every WAR file is loaded by separate classloader, thus cannot see each other.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/wlprg/classloading.html#GUID-5163D350-7BA6-4CD8-90DC-9FB9971C018A

https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/how-the-jvm-locates-loads-and-runs-libraries